# Modifying an access database in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've a Windows Form in Visual Studio 2017, with just a `DataGridView`. 
which is connected to an access database on my desktop. When I run my program, I can insert data or update data in my `DataGridView`. But it doesn't change anything in my access file. I think it just changes the local `dataset` during the program.

```
private string rq_sql;
private string cnx;

private System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection oCnx;
private System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand oCmd;
private System.Data.DataSet oDS;

private void btn_insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // insert content of textboxs when i click on the button
{
        this.actual_name = this.textBox2.Text;
        this.actual_phone = this.textBox1.Text;

        bg_matou = "INSERT INTO Table1(Telphone, Prenom) VALUES ('"+actual_phone+"','"+actual_name+"')";
        oCmd = new OleDbCommand(rq_sql, oCnx);
        oCnx.Open();
        oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        oCnx.Close();
        this.table1TableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet2.Table1);
}
```

My databse is well updated but locally on my program, I can't find a solution to modify it in the file. Thank you in advance for any help.

I found something about `OleDbCommandBuilder` but it is in VB .NET, and I don't really know about this.

Answer (score 1):

Example of OleDbDataAdapter in C#

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public class frmDatabase
{
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();

private void frmProject_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\xxx\\xxx\\xxx.mdb";
    con.Open();
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from table", con);
    da.Fill(dt);
    dgvDetails.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
    con.Close();
}


private void cmdUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\xxx\\xxx\\xxx.mdb";
    con.Open();
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from table", con);
    da.Update(dt);
    con.Close();

}
public frmDatabase()
{
    Load += frmProject_Load;
}
}
```

Comment: There are only select queries on your exemple. Would an INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE work and modify the access file ?

Comment: You can do it with: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.insertcommand(v=vs.110).aspx.